# Tweepy crawler: executing code while waiting for rate limit to restart

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

I am writing a crawler that gets info of users in twitter (its name, num of statuses, among others atributes of twitter's API User object). I activated `wait_on_rate_limit=True`, so that the program waits automatically when iterating over users and friends of users, etc. The crawler basically gets a user's friend list, picks a friend, and gets its friend list. However, when the rate limit is exceeded, it would be nice if the program could, for instance, load tweets from some of the users I loaded before (because rate limits of users and tweets are independent).

So the question is: how can I detect if the rate limit has been exceeded? Am I able then to execute some code to process information or to get more information of other kinds of API's objects?

Comment: Are you saying `wait_on_rate_limit=True` is not working?

Comment: @Leb no. It works but when it reaches the limit when visiting users, the program stops and I can't visit timelines.